# Java -- Objects & calling methods

Tags: java, object, methods

So I've been exercising quite a bit and I came across an error and I think I'm missing something important. Anyway here is the code.

```
public class Point {
    int x;
    int y;

    Point() {
        this(0, 0);
    }

    Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    void printPoint() {
        System.out.println("(" + x + "," + y + ")");
    }
}

public class MainPoint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Point p = new Point();
        p.x = 3;
        p.y = 4;
        ***printPoint();***
    }

}
```

But when I call the printPoint method it's underlined red. So what's the syntax in order to call a method that is NON-STATIC.
Thanks

PS Is there a difference between

```
Point p = new Point();
        p.x = 3;
        p.y = 4;
```

and

```
Point p = new Point(3, 4);
```

??

Comment: You need to call it on an instance of `Point` - e.g. `p.printPoint()`. Note that Stack Overflow isn't really a good way of learning the basics of the language - it would be a good idea to get a good book or tutorial, and read that... I'd expect any such resource to explain how to call methods.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks. Hahaha it's actually quite simple :p

Comment: Also, only ask one question per post.

Comment: They're not on the same matter - one is about calling two different constructors, and the other is how to call instance methods. Stack Overflow is meant to be a repository of questions and answers - which works best if each post asks a single question. Note that if you ask lots of questions which indicate a lack of research, they're likely to be downvoted... and if you ask enough unpopular questions, you will be automatically banned from asking more. You're a long way from that at the moment, but you should bear it in mind if you're thinking of "I can ask as many questions as I want"...